# Swift: How can I bind data to a view in a loop?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I want to bind data to an array of UIImageView-es by for-loop. But I don't know how to bind as simple as Javascript data attribute. 
I have an idea that making an array [UIImage : data] to do this. 
Ok, here is something wrong with my code:

Questions:

1. How to get its patternSelector in selectDecoration?
2. How to create outlets binding with data in a loop? For example, How can I bind every variable `pattern` to each action `selectDecoration()` ?

   ```
   func selectDecoration(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
       print("OK")
   }
   let patternSelectorHeight: CGFloat = 120        
   var i : Int = 0
   //var patternViews = [UIImageView]()
   for pattern in decorationPatterns {

       let patternSelector = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "test.jpg"))
       if let p = patternSelector.image {
           let proportion = p.size.width / p.size.height
           let w = proportion * patternSelectorHeight


           let patternX: CGFloat = (w + Conf.Size.margin) * CGFloat(i) + Conf.Size.margin
           let patternOrigin = CGPoint(x: patternX, y: decorationSelectionTitleHeight)

           patternSelector.userInteractionEnabled = true

           patternSelector.frame = CGRect(origin: patternOrigin, size: CGSize(width: w, height: patternSelectorHeight))
           patternSelector.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "selectDecoration:"))

           decorationBg.addSubview(patternSelector)
           decorationBg.bringSubviewToFront(patternSelector)
           //patternViews.append(patternSelector)

       }
       i++
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no inbuilt support for data binding in Swift. You need to keep a reference to your `UIImageView` objects, probably, as you suggest, in an array, so that you can update them later.

You need to set `patterSelector.userInteractionEnabled=true` for the `UITapGestureRecognizer` to work.

```
let patterSelectorSize = CGSize(width: 80.0, height: 160.0)
var imageViews = [UIImageView]()  // This probably needs to be an instance variable so you can access it outside of this function
var i : Int = 0
for _ in decorationPatterns {
    let patternX: CGFloat = (patterSelectorSize.width + 10) * CGFloat(i) + 10
    let patternOrigin = CGPoint(x: patternX, y: CGFloat(60))
    let patterSelector = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "default.jpeg"))
    patterSelector.frame = CGRect(origin: patternOrigin, size: patterSelectorSize)
    patterSelector.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "selectDecoration:"))
    patterSelector.userInteractionEnabled=true
    imageViews.append(patterSelector)

    decorationBg.addSubview(patterSelector)
    decorationBg.bringSubviewToFront(patterSelector)
    i++
}
```

You must also ensure that `userInteractionEnabled` is `true` in `decorationBg` otherwise touches won't be propagated to your image views

Comment: it almost the same as what I wrote. and it not works

Comment: I tested this code and it works for me.  What is `decorationBg`? Does it have `userInteractionEnabled=true`?  If not then the image views won't respond to taps

Comment: and how to bind data to each patternSelector?

Answer (score 0):

(1) How to create outlets binding with data in a loop?

If you would like to bind String data then try `accessibilityLabel` property. You can set & retrieve value silently.

(2) why the UITapGestureRecoginzer in follow doesn't work at all?

You missed to enable the `userInteractionEnabled` of your `UIImageView`

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I added userInteractionEnabled = true.  but still not works

Comment: Please enable the userInteractionEnabled of superview which is decorationBg in your case.

Comment: and how to bind data to each patternSelector?

Comment: What kind of data you would like to bind? String?

Comment: You can't bind data natively.  You can update the button text.  There are frameworks that people have developed for data binding, such as Reactive Cocoa.  You can search Google